# how in javascript to check with the help of regular expressions matches the mask and pattern to this mask?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a special input that will check the mask by the pattern of this mask for the correctness of the entered characters. I thought that I need to create an array with regular expressions for each character for the pattern. The pattern should include Latin and Cyrillic characters, spaces, dashes and underscores. I'm trying now to check if the check works, but anything can get into my input. What is the correct way to make sure that it checks the pattern and mask which characters should be included in the input?

```
export default {
  data: ()=>({
    plate_pattern:{
      app11le: "AAA11AA",
      cherr11y:"AAAA11A",
      a111pricot: "A111AAAAA"
    },
    pattern_key: this.plate_pattern,
    handler: "",
    mask: [{app11le:' ___ __ __'}, {cherr11y: '____ ___'}, {a111pricot: '_ _______'}],
    placeholder: '_',
    start: 0,
    isRight: true,

  }),

 methods:{
    isNumber(checkIfNumber){
      return !isNaN(checkIfNumber) && parseInt(+checkIfNumber) == checkIfNumber() && !isNaN(parseInt(checkIfNumber, 10))
    },
    isLetter(checkIfLetter){
      return isNaN(checkIfLetter) && checkIfLetter.toLowerCase() != checkIfLetter.toLowerCase() && checkIfLetter.length == 1
    },
    isRightSymbol(checkIfSymbolInArray){
      let arraySymbolExist = [
          {name: 'app11le', regex: /^[\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][0-9_][\wа-я][\wа-я]$/, check: true},
        {name:'cherr11y', regex:/^[\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][0-9_][\wа-я]$/, check: true },
        {name:'a111pricot', regex: /^[\wа-я][0-9_][0-9_][0-9_][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я][\wа-я]$/ }
      ]
  if(arraySymbolExist.length){
  for (let i = 0; i < arraySymbolExist.length; i++) {
    return !checkIfSymbolInArray.match(arraySymbolExist[i])
  }
}
    },
    inputFruitName(fruitsName){
      if(this.isNumber(fruitsName.key) || this.isLetter(fruitsName.key) && this.isRightSymbol(fruitsName.key)){
        this.isRight = false;
      }
    },
```

Comment: in your `isRightSymbol` function, why is there no looping logic? you're trying to `match` with an array, that should lead to a method undefined error. Please check your console log if that is true.

Comment: hi @SamridhTuladhar I edited my code but I am very new to Vue.js and JS itself because I am from the mobile-dev world, so can you check and give me a hint how where should I place for-loop, please? I was trying to do it outside the isRightSymbol function but it couldn't see the array of regex, so I decided to place it inside

Comment: do not use the `return` statement inside the `for` loop, it will cause it to not loop at all, and will only work for one iteration, you need to save the result in a variable, and then return that variable instead, once the loop is completed. basically `if(found) return true` inside the for loop, please do more research on the debugger, i'm more of a react person so i don't know how that would work there, but a debugger would help you big time, and then we can worry about the regex, we shouldn't be solving multiple problems here.